# HP OO inputs and REST API

Tags: json, rest

i'm working on HP Operations orchestration software for automating flows. 
I need to resume a flow by passing inputs to steps. 
the json body used is like above :

```
{
```

"action":"RESUME",
"data":{

"branchId" : null,

"input_binding" : {

```
 "identityEndpoint":"http://192.1.1.184:5000" ,

  "authToken" : "gAAAAABZAhe7nhuzcq2JXftYv1Ta181Dm6Bfa2UsfCXVuqVppPc-xkUGJ-SjcqoYvntDO25gqW7qitsZpuLVjJ9-4ItaaaPDpoaX_Ys53KGZ8ZB_GL2Y8hvnZ8iAsudj0uO464H2wX5G3k-fgZSOfqwqGbK1sSS9zSHN1Ci9yirHLX6AmnuNJL8" ,
  "userName" : "gara" }
```

}
}

But still doesn't work. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I know you might have got the answer already, but, did you use, "Prompt User" for that specific component when defining.
It takes a default value, when the user doesn't enter any information on the popup text field.

Comment: Hi there. I already used "Prompt User" when creating and defining the flow that i need. The problem was in The software API. It means that The API does not acccept the "network" variable as a "Prompt User" passed value. I was obliged so to pass it with a default value. That was the problem. Thank you for your interest.